# OpenOffice API: How to turn off headers and footers

Tags: java, api, openoffice.org

I am struggling to make sense of the OpenOffice API. Thanks to SO I worked out how to turn on line numbering. Now I need to turn off headers and footers.
Getting the XPropertySet of a document XComponent 
XPropertySet propSet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, document);

and setting

propSet.setPropertyValue("HeaderIsOn", Boolean.FALSE);
  propSet.setPropertyValue("FooterIsOn", Boolean.FALSE);

is not working. Like a lot of others I cannot make sense of the documentation.

I have seen a Perl example ([Perl OpenOffice::OODoc - accessing header/footer elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021610/perl-openofficeoodoc-accessing-header-footer-elements)) and cannot work out how to get the "master page" header/styles in Java.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the page style and set its properties.  Here is the code that worked for me:

```
 XStyleFamiliesSupplier xSupplier = (XStyleFamiliesSupplier)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XStyleFamiliesSupplier.class, xTextDocument);
 XNameAccess xFamilies = (XNameAccess) UnoRuntime.queryInterface ( 
    XNameAccess.class, xSupplier.getStyleFamilies());
 XNameContainer xFamily = (XNameContainer) UnoRuntime.queryInterface( 
    XNameContainer.class, xFamilies.getByName("PageStyles"));
// The style name may be "Default Style" or just "Default" -- check your document.  
XStyle xStyle = (XStyle) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XStyle.class, xFamily.getByName("Default Style"));
XPropertySet xStyleProps = (XPropertySet) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XPropertySet.class, xStyle);
xStyleProps.setPropertyValue ("HeaderIsOn", Boolean.FALSE);
xStyleProps.setPropertyValue ("FooterIsOn", Boolean.FALSE);
```

Perl UNO examples can be tricky, perhaps because they use their own special OpenOffice library.  Instead, I found these to be helpful:

- [Styles Example](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Overall_Document_Features#Styles) in Java, at the bottom of the page.
- [Changing the Text of Headers and Footers](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Formatting_Spreadsheet_Documents), a Basic example in the middle of the page.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that did the trick. Those links which I had blundered past now make sense. Headers and Footers are style properties rather than 'page' or 'document' properties.

Comment: One day I will track down a poster version of the ODF API something like this one Microsoft provide for their "Open Office" Javascript  API https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36850